# Using regular expression in Java to extract date from string in the format 01OCT12 14:26

Tags: java, regex, date

I am looking to read dates from either a file or String in the format 01OCT12 14:26

I know the dates will be of either the month OCT or NOV which may help me write a more precise regex expression.

I have read of quite a few option Java provides for using regex such as Matcher & Pattern and also the Scanner class and was hoping for help to find the cleanest way of tackling this.

Comment: Where in the string? Anywhere?

Comment: I tried to provide with a detailed explanation; hopefully it helps.  Since you're new, check out: [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it with regular expressions, with an example:

```
        String example = "01OCT12 14:26";
        String pattern = "^(\\d{2})(?:OCT|NOV)(\\d{2}) (\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2})$";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(example);

        if (m.find()) 
        {
            //prints example
            System.out.println(m.group());

            System.out.println(m.group(1)); //prints 01
            System.out.println(m.group(2)); //prints 12
            System.out.println(m.group(3)); //prints 14
            System.out.println(m.group(4)); //prints 26
        }
```

`"^(\\d{2})(?:OCT|NOV)(\\d{2}) (\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2})$"` breakdown:

- `^` means begins with
- `(...)` is a capturing group, meaning that `...` is a pattern that you want to capture

  - In this case, the pattern is `\\d{2}`, which means two of any digit in `[0-9]`
- `(?:OCT|NOV)`

  - `?:` means do NOT capture the following
  - `OCT|NOV` means must be either OCT or NOV
- `(\\d{1,2})` is a capture group that matches 1 or 2 numbers `[0-9]`
- Finally, `$` means ends with

You may not want to use regular expressions to accomplish this task; nonetheless, I believe that this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, regex might not be the most efficient way but you've satisfied my curiosity.

Comment: No problem.  If you haven't checked out [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about), you should.  SO is an awesome source site.

Answer (score 5):

If you know where in the string the date is, you could use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for parsing instead of using a regex:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMMdd kk:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date result = df.parse(stringDate);
```

(I assumed that `01` was the year and `12` was the day, but if it's reversed, then you would need to reverse the `yy` and `dd` in the date format string.)

Comment: Thanks, Yes I do, its right at the start so I could take a substring and try to parse it.